# Is it a good practice to use 'nofollow' on internal links in a multi-language website?

Tags: seo, multilingual, nofollow, hyperlink

I've a website which is in `en-US` and `fr-FR` and I'm building links for the `en` version of the website.

Should I put all the `fr` links on the English version `nofollow`? Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

No, instead of that just use rel="alternate" tag, as the google [documentation](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html) recommends:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://example.com/es/my-page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en/my-page/" />
```